# How can i print 2d array as grid in python with dashes and + symbol?

Tags: python

I am currently working on developing a connect 4 game for which i need 2d array but the issue is i want to print 2d array in such a way that it prints with dashes (-) and (+) symbol .Also i need to print the rows and column numbers alongside each row and column. Also when ever the user enters his turn it should be displayed in appropriate cell. Here is my code which is not working properly

```
board=[['','','','','',''],['','','','','',''],['','','','','',''],
   ['','','','','',''],['','','','','',''],['','','','','','']]
i=0
j=0
for r in board:
    print(i,end="|")
    for c in r:
       print('+',end="---")
       print(c,end="")
    print('+')
    i=i+1
```

Output is like follow :

```
0|+---+---+---+---+---+---+
1|+---+---+---+---+---+---+
2|+---+---+---+---+---+---+
3|+---+---+---+---+---+---+
4|+---+---+---+---+---+---+
5|+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

but i want something like this

```
    0   1   2    3   4  5
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
0| x |   |   |   |   |   | 
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
1|   |   |   |   |   |   |
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
2|   |   |   |   |   |   |
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
3|   |   |   |   |   |   |
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
4|   |   |   |   |   |   |
```

where x is the symbol which i need to stored in 2d array and print at appropriate location. Any solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a nice [code golf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229998) for the main portion of this task, but I guess this might be a little to confusing to build up from that.

So, by taking some of these ideas and combining it with your code I came up with

```py
board = [['', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', ''],
         ['', '', '', '', '', ''],
         ['', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', ''],
         ['', '', '', '', '', '']]

x_loc = (2,5)
x_symbol = "X"

# print column numbers on top
columns = len(board[0])
print('   ', '   '.join([str(val) for val in range(columns)]))

row_separator = f'  +{"---+" * columns}'

for i_row, r in enumerate(board):
    print(row_separator)
    # print row number
    print(i_row, end="")
    # depending on location of X, either print a row including X or an empty row
    if i_row == x_loc[0]:
        print(f' |{"   |" * (x_loc[1])} {x_symbol} |{"   |" * (columns-x_loc[1]-1)}')
    else:
        print(f' |{"   |" * columns}')
# print closing row separator
print(row_separator)
```

which results in:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+
0 |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+
1 |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+
2 |   |   |   |   |   | X |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+
3 |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+
4 |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+
5 |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: can you go  a little bit deeper by explaining what is for ?

Comment: i have added some explanatory comments to the code @xlmaster